# iOS crash reports: how to find more informations

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Bellow there is a crash report provided by Apple:

```
{"bundleID":"RomaniaMilitary.RomaniaMilitary","app_name":"RomaniaMilitary","bug_type":"109","name":"RomaniaMilitary","os_version":"iPhone OS 7.1.1 (11D201)","version":"1.0 (1.0)"}
Incident Identifier: 1A9B2804-2C07-4E6B-9377-D396F56704CC
CrashReporter Key:   99f9caadfd48c4739585b7383898f343220c933c
Hardware Model:      xxx
Process:             RomaniaMilitary [457]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/A07BCAC9-34FA-459D-9231-C21476488D31/RomaniaMilitary.app/RomaniaMilitary
Identifier:          RomaniaMilitary.RomaniaMilitary
Version:             1.0 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-05-15 10:20:18.368 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
(0x18ab26f50 0x1975041fc 0x18ab2bc04 0x18ab29930 0x18aa495dc 0x100074360 0x18dc38904 0x18dbd6e64 0x18dbd662c 0x18daeaff8 0x18d6dc258 0x18d6d6e20 0x18d6d6cd8 0x18d6d6560 0x18d6d6304 0x18d6cfc38 0x18aae76a8 0x18aae4930 0x18aae4cbc 0x18aa25c20 0x1906c5c0c 0x18db56fdc 0x100074e30 0x197af7aa0)

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf258c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x0000000197b86804 abort + 108
2   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196dac990 abort_message + 84
3   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196dc9c28 default_terminate_handler() + 296
4   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001975044d0 _objc_terminate() + 124
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196dc7164 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 12
6   libc++abi.dylib                 0x0000000196dc6a7c __cxa_throw + 132
7   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000197504314 objc_exception_throw + 340
8   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ab2bc00 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 216
9   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018ab2992c ___forwarding___ + 908
10  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aa495d8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 88
11  RomaniaMilitary                 0x000000010007435c 0x100068000 + 50012
12  UIKit                           0x000000018dc38900 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 404
13  UIKit                           0x000000018dbd6e60 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 1928
14  UIKit                           0x000000018dbd6628 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 164
15  UIKit                           0x000000018daeaff4 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 344
16  QuartzCore                      0x000000018d6dc254 -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 180
17  QuartzCore                      0x000000018d6d6e1c CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 296
18  QuartzCore                      0x000000018d6d6cd4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 28
19  QuartzCore                      0x000000018d6d655c CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
20  QuartzCore                      0x000000018d6d6300 CA::Transaction::commit() + 420
21  QuartzCore                      0x000000018d6cfc34 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
22  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae76a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
23  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae492c __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
24  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae4cb8 __CFRunLoopRun + 760
25  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aa25c1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001906c5c08 GSEventRunModal + 164
27  UIKit                           0x000000018db56fd8 UIApplicationMain + 1152
28  RomaniaMilitary                 0x0000000100074e2c 0x100068000 + 52780
29  libdyld.dylib                   0x0000000197af7a9c start + 0

Thread 1 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bd9aa8 kevent64 + 8
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000197add998 _dispatch_mgr_thread + 48

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 4 name:  AFNetworking
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bd9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae6b70 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae4d00 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aa25c1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   Foundation                      0x000000018b5c12c0 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 292
5   Foundation                      0x000000018b61ed74 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 92
6   RomaniaMilitary                 0x000000010008332c 0x100068000 + 111404
7   Foundation                      0x000000018b6a8408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c73e18 _pthread_body + 164
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c73d70 _pthread_start + 136
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71550 thread_start + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bd9ca0 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae6b70 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 180
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aae4d00 __CFRunLoopRun + 832
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000018aa25c1c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 448
4   Foundation                      0x000000018b61a424 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 344
5   Foundation                      0x000000018b6a8408 __NSThread__main__ + 996
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c73e18 _pthread_body + 164
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c73d70 _pthread_start + 136
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71550 thread_start + 0

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf2e74 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71548 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000197bf276c __select + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c73e18 _pthread_body + 164
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c73d70 _pthread_start + 136
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000197c71550 thread_start + 0

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x000000016fd93ee8
    x4: 0x0000000000002060   x5: 0x000000016fd93fa0   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000a20
    x8: 0x0000000008000000   x9: 0x0000000004000000  x10: 0x000000009aa3f6f7  x11: 0x0000000000000300
   x12: 0x0000000000000000  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000197b9fdcb
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x005bf73d22a9626a  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x000000019aa522a0  x21: 0x0000000170126318  x22: 0x0000000170126340  x23: 0x00000001987304f0
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x000000018e1e51ea  x26: 0x000000014fd354f0  x27: 0x00000001702a12c0
   x28: 0x00000001700388a0  fp: 0x000000016fd93f20   lr: 0x0000000197c7516c
    sp: 0x000000016fd93f00   pc: 0x0000000197bf258c cpsr: 0x00000000
```

Update :

Apple message:
We found your app crashed on launch so we were unable to review it. Please revise your app and test it on a device to ensure it will launch without crashing, and that it runs as expected, before resubmitting.

I posted full report (without binary image)

Comment: What did they say to you? They wouldn't have just sent you this, they would have said something.

Comment: You need to symbolicate that crash dump in order to find out what `0x100068000 + 50012` is, as it appears to be the root cause of your crash.

Comment: It's bogus that this question was closed after the submitter included the extra information.

Answer (score 2):

You submitted an application without symbols, so Apple couldn't tell you where in your application the fault is. The last bit of your code that is called gets called from

```
[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:]
```

so it will happen in some delegate method of yours where you are preparing a cell, and you are sending a message to some object that doesn't understand it. There's probably more information in their report which you should post. Knowing which method was sent to which kind of object would be very helpful.

Meanwhile, turn on all warnings in your compiler that you can reasonably turn on and fix the problems, then run the static analyser and fix all problems that it finds, then let someone else test your application on a real device, in case you subconsciously avoid problem areas.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do:

1) You need your archived application, the one you submitted. If not, then disregard the rest of the steps; it's game over.

2) The archive file is a bundle. You must show its contents.

3) Inside you will find a folder marked 'dSYMs.' Inside it you will find a file named `<your app name>.app.dSYM.` Select it and copy (using Copy/Command-C).

4) Go back one level. Inside the Products/Applications folder you will find your application. It's a bundle as well. You must show its contents.

5) Inside you will find your application's executable file. Now paste the dSYM file you had previously copied here.

6) Fire up your Terminal. cd to the Products/Applications folder in which you just pasted the dSYM file.

7) Now go back to that 'cryptic' report that Apple sent you. I see that you've included more information from the report, but there ought to be a section that shows all the processes that were running on your device at the time, and at the top should be your application. There are two large hexadecimal numbers there. Make a note of the first one. Then go to line 11 in your stack trace. Make a note of that long hexadecimal (0x000000010007435c). You'll need both of these numbers for the next step.

8) On your Terminal's command line enter

```
atos -o <your application name, including the extension> -l <first hex number> <second hex number>
```

9) atos should show you something like this:

```
-[classname method] (in <your app name>) (<file name where your object is located>:<line number>)
```

Now you'll have the clue you need to go after your problem.

Good luck to you in your endeavors.

Comment: I followed your steps…
I copied MyApp.app.dSYM in Products/Applications/MyApp.app
tried following commands : 
atos -o MyApp -l 0x000000010007435c 0x100068000
atos cannot load symbols for the file MyApp for architecture i386.

atos -o MyApp -arch armv7 -l 0x000000010007435c 0x100068000
got symbolicator for MyApp, base address 4000
0x100068000

Comment: You've got your numbers turned around. 0x000000010007435c should always be the *second* number.